# Access CloudWatch Logs

Tags: c#, aws-sdk

I want to access the Cloud Watch logs from the AWS account using c#

I tried exploring about **AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient** class for connecting AWS but did'nt get the expected code.

```
var awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access_key", "secret_key");

AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient awscloudwatch = new 
AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient(awsCredentials,RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

GetLogGroupFieldsRequest logFieldRequest = new GetLogGroupFieldsRequest();
logFieldRequest.LogGroupName = "SampleLogs"; 

var fields = awscloudwatch.GetLogGroupFieldsAsync(logFieldRequest);
```

Using Above code fields.Result is always null

Comment: what exactly is the code you have tried?

Comment: @danimal Thanks...i edited in my question

Answer (score 0):

you need to **await** the async

var fields = await awscloudwatch.GetLogGroupFieldsAsync(logFieldRequest);